# JS window.addEventListener Only Works On One Page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JavaScript if element is on screen function which is triggered by a window.addEventListener. When a specific div is in view then CSS classes are added (from Animate CSS) to a div element. The code only works on one page of my website and not on the others.

I get this console error only on the second page (where the JS doesn't work)

```
TypeError: $elem.offset(...) is undefined
```

**Live Project URL**:

```
// Element In View function

function isOnScreen(elem) {
    // if the element doesn't exist, abort
    if (elem.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var $window = jQuery(window)
    var viewport_top = $window.scrollTop()
    var viewport_height = $window.height()
    var viewport_bottom = viewport_top + viewport_height
    var $elem = jQuery(elem)
    var top = $elem.offset().top
    var height = $elem.height()
    var bottom = top + height

    return (bottom > viewport_top) && (top < viewport_bottom)
}

// Animation when element is in view

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    if (isOnScreen('#lfdesign')) {
        $("#lfdesign .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInRight");
    }
    if (isOnScreen('#books')) {
        $("#books .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInLeft");
    }
    if (isOnScreen('.srp-color')) {
        $(".srp-color .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInRight");
    }
    if (isOnScreen('.nescol-color')) {
        $(".nescol-color .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInLeft");
    }
    if (isOnScreen('.worldskills-color')) {
        $(".worldskills-color .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInRight");
    }
    if (isOnScreen('.silvernote-color')) {
        $(".silvernote-color .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInLeft");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
```

HTML

```
<section class="left silvernote-color">

    <div class="flexcontainer">

        <div class="flex-item">

            <a href="webdesign/silvernote">

                <img class="normal" src="img/silvernote-logo.png" alt="The logo for SilverNote, a music enterprise hub in Aberdeen who I helped to create a responsive site for by adding artist profiles with a team of developers">

            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">

            <p>SilverNote Music is a music enterprise hub in Aberdeen that want to promote new music. They tasked me and three others to work as a team to create a responsive site that catered to those viewing on computers as well as a younger, mobile audience.</p>

            <p>My main responsibilities were communicating with our client and developing the artist page. I pitched the prototype to the wider organisation and gathered feedback from the band members. This feedback informed the music players I created on the artist profiles.</p>

        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Is the `JavaScript` file linked on every page?

Comment: @goto1, Yes, it is.


`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>`

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're seeing `TypeError: $elem.offset(...) is undefined` is because you're trying to call the `offset` method on an element that does not exist on your page.

You should change your logic that checks if an element exists. Currently, your function `isOnScreen` takes a string as an argument and checks if the `length` of that `string` is `0` - this doesn't actually check if the element is on the page or not.

```js
function isOnScreen(elem) {
  if (elem.length == 0) {
    return
  }
}

window.addEventListener(`scroll`, function (e) {
  if (isOnScreen(`#lfdesign`) {
    // passing a string and checking it's length
    // inside the `isOnScreen` function doesn't tell
    // you if this element is on the page or not
  }
})
```

Instead, what you should do is try to grab/find the element first with `jQuery`, if that's what you prefer, and check if exists. If so, do whatever you need to do, otherwise `return` early.

```js
function isOnScreen(selector) {
  var el = $(selector)
  
  if (el.length !== 1) {
    console.log(`element ${selector} does not exist!`)
    return;
  }
  console.log(`element ${selector} exists!`)
  // do work
}

// inside of `window.addEventListener` callback function

if (isOnScreen("#lfdesign")) {
 // do work
}

if (isOnScreen("#books")) {
  // do work
}

if (isOnScreen(".srp-color")) {
  // do work
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lfdesign">
  <h4>My ID is <b>lfdesign</b>!</h4>
</div>
<div id="books">
  <h4>My ID is <b>books</b>!</h4>
</div>
```

One note that I'd like to make is that `window.addEventListener("scroll", callback)` will get called a lot in a short amount of time which might cause performance issues. If you're running into issues with performance, you should look at `throttling` and/or `debouncing`:

- [The Difference Between Throttling and Debouncing - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Added `el.addClass("animated slower bounceInRight");` underneath `console.log(`element ${selector} exists!`)` which works on all pages but the if isOnScreen triggers on window reload not when the element is visible in the device viewport.

Comment: @LouiseFindlay are you saying `if (isOnScreen(...))` is only called once, when the page loads for the first time and now when you scroll? Put those `if` statements inside of the `callback` function for the `window.addEventListener("scroll", callback)` scroll listener. The code snippet I added above was simplified, but it sounds like it solves your original issue.

Comment: Something like this?

`window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {

        if (isOnScreen('#lfdesign')) {
            $("#lfdesign .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInRight");
        }
        if (isOnScreen('#books')) {
            $("#books .flexcontainer").addClass("animated slower bounceInLeft");
        }
    });`

Comment: @LouiseFindlay yes, exactly how it's in your original example, but with the fixes I applied in the code snippets above.

Comment: it's still triggering all of them at once. I think it's the ` el.addClass("animated slower bounceInRight");` line I added but without it nothing happens at all.

`function isOnScreen(selector) {
        var el = $(selector)

        if (el.length !== 1) {
            console.log(`element ${selector} does not exist!`)
            return;
        }
        console.log(`element ${selector} exists!`)
        el.addClass("animated slower bounceInRight");
    }`

Comment: @LouiseFindlay you're saying when you scroll it's triggering all of them at once? If that's the case, then it sounds like your logic inside of `isOnScreen` is wrong and not properly returning `true` or `false` when your elements are visible and not visible.

Comment: if I put the `isOnScreen` lines related to divs on the **second page** inside the `$(window).scroll(function ()` then they don't trigger but the `isOnScreen` lines related to divs on the **first page** do (and only when the particular element is visible in the viewport as desired. Taking the 'isOnScreen' lines related to divs on the **second page** outside the `$(window).scroll(function ()` makes them trigger but all at once on page load.

Comment: @LouiseFindlay are you actually scrolling on the second page and do you have the same elements on that second page?

Comment: @got1, yes, I'm scrolling on the second page and they are different elements but have been added to the script.js file. I've also tried adding different selectors to the new elements such as ids but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @LouiseFindlay It's hard to say what the problem is without knowing/seeing the code.

Comment: @got1, here is the [repo](https://github.com/louisefindlay23/louisefindlay23.github.io)

Comment: @LouiseFindlay your `if` statements are outside of `$(window).scroll(...)` so that'd make sense why they're only triggered once and not every time you scroll - https://github.com/louisefindlay23/louisefindlay23.github.io/blob/master/js/script.js#L89. Also, you never fixed your `isOnScreen` function the way I have it up top - https://github.com/louisefindlay23/louisefindlay23.github.io/blob/master/js/script.js#L54

Comment: here's the [fixes](https://github.com/louisefindlay23/louisefindlay23.github.io/commit/32b397ca29801d6413a7c1ef086242aaa5719969).

Comment: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using [jQuery.inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) plugin instead.